# Export only selected checkbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have function export and print only table.

snippet code like this

```js
r  = 'myTable';
r = $("#" + r).clone();
$(".result").append(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>  
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  
</table>

<h1>export result</h1>

<div class="result">
  
</div>
```

how to clone table to export only selected checkbox ?

Comment: You are already cloning the table and placing the clone fine in the div. What is specific problem? Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask] then edit the question with a  properly detailed problem description

Comment: i mean, this my fuction now and this function export to all in table. and my answer how to clone only selected row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can remove (or hide) the unchecked rows from clone something like

```js
r  = 'myTable';
r = $("#" + r).clone();
r.find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').remove();// or hide()
$(".result").append(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none">
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>  
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td> 
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td> 
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
</div>
<h1>export result</h1>

<div class="result">
  
</div>
```